# view gets blank after adding cookies dependency angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Angular view gets blank after adding bellow code, i have included already angular cookies library

```
  angular
.module('app', ['ngCookies']).controller('loginCtrl', function($scope,$http,$window,$cookieStore){
//code
});
```

Comment: Maybe a typo, but I don't see the closing ```)``` of your controller code. Besides $cookieStore is deprecated. Do you have any error on the console?

Comment: no i dont have any error in console

Comment: Try injecting ```$cookies``` instead of ```$cookieStore```.

Comment: that too not working,